# Stieltjes integral with floor mass function

Tags: integration

I need to express as a finite sum the Stieltjes integral $\int_{0+}^{n+}f(x)\,dg(x)$ with $f$ continuous and $g(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$. My understanding is that since $g(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ is a constant, we get 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)([x_{i+1}]-[x_i])$$

 I appreciate your help.

Comment: How did $f$ disappear in your answer?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I forgot, I edited. Thanks.

Comment: @abenol When do you have $[x_{i+1}]-[x_i] \neq 0$?

Comment: @Gary when $x_i+1$ is the $\lceil x \rceil$ (next higher integer?